# Is there any configurations that need to be done to connect Arduino Uno and Bluetooth Bee?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I currently have Arduino Uno and Bluetooth Bee and the Shield i use is the Xbee Shield Pro v1.4.
There are couple of jumpers in the Xbee Shield pro; one is the XBEe/USB jumper and the other one is the Run /Prog jumper. I was wondering what they are used for and if they need to be configure before i can upload any program to the arduino uno.

Comment: I haven't used XBee stuff yet, but that's on my list. The XBEE switch is to choose between microcontroller or the PC (USB). Not sure what the run/prog jumper is for. That is also a 3.3V peripheral so you'll need to limit the voltage or use a logic leveler to avoid burning it out. I've written code for Seeed's bluetooth shield.

Comment: oh..is that code for the bluetooth shield to communicate with the UNO???